# List built by a loop that overwrites

Tags: r, list, loops, overwrite

I am trying to generate a list in R composed by 50 elements. In each element should be a pair of numbers in the following way:
`[[1]] 14 64 
[[2]] 15 65
... 
[[50]] 63 113`

I have tried by making up this loop, but there is something going wrong I don't get to figure out:

```
cons<- list()
for (k in seq(1:50)){
  for (i in 14:63){
    for (j in 64:113){
      cons[[k]] <- c(i,j)         
    }
  }
}
```

I have also tried with `seq(lenght())` and `seq_along()` as a way go make the loop go through all the values one by one, but still doesn't work. I apologize this is not a new question, but after reading through others I still don't find a solution for this case.

Thanks a lot before hand for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways to do that..

```
X <- 14:63
Y <- 64:113
lapply(1:50, FUN = function(i) c(X[i], Y[i]))
## [[1]]
## [1] 14 64
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 15 65
## 
## ....
## ....
## ....
## 
## [[50]]
## [1]  63 113
```

Or

```
mapply(FUN = function(x,y) {c(x,y)}, x = 14:63, y = 64:113, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Or using plain loops

```
X <- 14:63
Y <- 64:113
cons<- list()
for (k in seq(1:50)){
    cons[[k]] <- c(X[k],Y[k])         
}
```

The mistake in OP's code is following creates 50*50 iterations. so the pairs generated are `c(14,64), c(14,65) ... c(63,112), c(63,113)`. Only first 50 of this are put into the list. And this process is just repeated 50 times.

```
for (i in 14:63){
    for (j in 64:113){
      cons[[k]] <- c(i,j)         
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! now I see were the mistake was.

Comment: Or just `Map(c, X, Y)`